# How to write a output of a Python in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

How to write a output of Python in a text file in Python? Below is the code and tried Open file function and it is not working

```
Code:
====
import os
# folder path
file_path = "/emp_Files/"
# list to store files
res = []
# Iterate directory
for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        res.append(file)
print(res)
f=open("/emp_Files/output.txt","w")
for res in result:
    print >> f, res
f.close()


Output:
=======
info_0_1_0.csv
info_0_2_0.csv
info_0_3_0.csv


Required output in txt file:
===========================
info_0_1_0.csv
info_0_2_0.csv
info_0_3_0.csv
```

Comment: How is it failing, and what exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: Note that as written now, `"/emp_Files/"`will open a directory in the root of the file system (`/` on a Unix-like system, `C:\ ` on Windows). If you need it to open a sub-directory in current working path, the remove the first `/`.

Comment: `print(res, file=f)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use savetxt() function from the 'numpy' module :

```py
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('/emp_Files/output.txt', res)
```

res is your the variable for the resulting list